# Send a callback through to another class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an infinite scroll class:

```
p.infiniteScrollFnc = undefined;

p.init = function() {
    this.infiniteScrollFnc = this.infiniteScroll.bind(this);
};

p.initInfiniteScroll = function(cb){
    $(window).on('scroll', this.infiniteScrollFnc.bind(cb));
};

p.terminateInfiniteScroll = function(){
    $(window).off('scroll', this.infiniteScrollFnc);
};

p.infiniteScroll = function(cb){
    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){

        console.log('load more');
        this.terminateInfiniteScroll();
        cb();
    }
};
```

I wish to send a callback through, I do this in another class via:

```
this.infiniteScroll.initInfiniteScroll(this.myCallback);
```

But I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: cb is not a function
```

Comment: See if you can find a non-minified version of the library you're using. The error should be more descriptive then.

Comment: `$(window).on('scroll', p.infiniteScrollFnc.bind(cb));`

Comment: so where's myCallback function?

Comment: The object `cb` that you are sending through all those functions is not a function when you try to call it as one...

Comment: Bhojendra Nepal not included as it's just a console log test fnc.

Comment: Halcyon it's not a lib, I wrote it.

Comment: You are binding the "this" scope to an event??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass `cb` using bind, then you put it as the second parameter, because the first on is context:

```
p.initInfiniteScroll = function (cb) {
    $(window).on('scroll', this.infiniteScrollFnc.bind(this, cb));
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/t6cnvudo/